# Merging two datasets rows based on a single column variable

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a two dataframes in R containing the same type of data (same variables). For this example I named them `blank` and `data`.

```html
>blank    
    Prey  Sample Value
1   act1      IP    0
2   act1    Mock    0
3   act2      IP    0
4   act2    Mock    0
5   act3      IP    0


>data
    Prey  Sample Value
1   act1      IP  2.2
2   act1    Mock    0
3   act3      IP  3.6
4   act3      IP  3.1
5   act3      IP  2.1
```

I'd like to combine the two dataframes into one. I want to keep all the rows from `data` intact while adding all the rows from `blank` that are missing in `data` according ONLY to `Prey` column. To be clear, I don't need `union`, since I don't want to consider the *entire* row contents, but just the content of the `Prey` column to merge the two datasets.
Below is the expected result for this small example, where rows with `act2` from `blank` were added while the rows from `data` were left intact.

```html
>result    
    Prey  Sample Value
1   act1      IP  2.2
2   act1    Mock    0
3   act3      IP  3.6
4   act3      IP  3.1
5   act3      IP  2.1
6   act2      IP    0
4   act2    Mock    0
```

I looked around for a while for an easy solution but I am still stuck. Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dyplr` solution using `anti_join` and `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

blank %>% 
  anti_join(data, by="Prey") %>% 
  bind_rows(data, .) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

```
  Prey  Sample Value
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 act1  IP       2.2
2 act1  Mock     0  
3 act3  IP       3.6
4 act3  IP       3.1
5 act3  IP       2.1
6 act2  IP       0  
7 act2  Mock     0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rbind(
  data,
  blank[!blank$Prey %in% data$Prey,]
)
```